# IE8 returns 'Object expected' prototype

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have this code, that works good on all browser and IE9> , but in IE8 it throws me 
`JScript Object Expected` on the first line (`Array.prototype...`)

```
this.items = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.el.id + ' > li' ) );
            this.itemsCount = this.items.length;
            this.itemsRenderedCount = 0;
            this.didScroll = false;
```

I tried changing
`document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.el.id + ' > li' )` to 
`$(this).attr("id")` - same error.

But when i change this line to simple jquery picker , for example `$("#someId")` , it works fine.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: As both QSA (with CSS2 selectors only) and slice is supported in IE8, it's probably the wrong selector and no element is returned.

Comment: what does `console.log('#' + this.el.id + ' > li')` output

Comment: I checked it , all the elements exist (console log returns: `#scroll-fade-effect1 > li 
#scroll-fade-effect2 > li
#scroll-fade-effect3 > li
#scroll-fade-effect4 > li  `

Comment: It'll never make any difference if the elements exist or not. A collection will always be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because IE8 and lower requires a native object as the `this` value of built-in Array methods. The collection you're passing is a host object.

You need to do the conversion manually instead.

Here's a simple example:

```
function _slice(arr) {
    try {   // try using .slice()
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
    } catch(e) {
            // otherwise, manually create the array
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
            result.push(arr[i]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
this.items = _slice( document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.el.id + ' > li' ) );
```

---

Side note, since `this.el` must be a `ul` or `ol` element, and so its children must be `li` elements, why not just do this?

```
this.items = _slice( this.el.children );
```